# How to download an executable jar via browser?

Tags: java, swing, servlets, java-web-start, corrupt

I'm unable to open a downloaded executable jar. I have a web app that is used to download the jar via browser to the client side. The file comes through just fine, but I get the message:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
```

I am also not able to open the file with 7zip . What's going on there?

The app is a JavaFx application that works perfectly locally , but when transmitted via serlvet / browser becomes corrupted.

I also wasn't able to get webstart to work due to very high policy setting and resulting classloading issues.

my rest endpoint:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fetchTool", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void downloadTool(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs();
    Optional<URL> appPath = Arrays.stream(urls).filter(x->x.getPath().contains("myTool")).findFirst();

    if (appPath.isPresent()){

        String[] fileParts = appPath.get().getPath().split("/");


        response.addHeader(CONTENT, ATTACHMENT + fileParts[fileParts.length - 1]);
        response.setContentType("application/java-archive");

        try (final InputStream input = new FileInputStream(appPath.get().getFile());
             final OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {
             IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException("File Not Found " + appPath.get().getPath(), e);
        }
    }else{
        throw new NotFoundException("MyTool Not Found on classpath");
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some code for the servlet.

Comment: These seem like two very separate problems. I'd advise sorting them out on separate question threads. For the first one, I'd heed the advice of @FedericoklezCulloca & post a [mcve] of the servlet code.

Comment: Try `response.setContentType("application/jar");`

Answer (score 1):

The error was on Angularjs side, I didn't set responseType to arrayBuffer.

wasn't on Java side afterall.

should be :

```
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: fileTransformer,
            dataType:"binary",
            processData : false,
            responseType : 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":undefined,
                "accept": 'application/octet-stream'
            }
```

Comment: Plus one for not only sorting it yourself, but reporting back.